# turning python output into string variable using exec()

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to turn python output into string variable using exec()

Something like this is the goal:

```
code = "print(3)"

string = exec(code) # string should then equal 3
```

Sorry if this was repeated. I couldn't find the solution anywhere.
Thanks

Comment: You must explain why you absolutely need to use exec(), as solutions that do not use `exec` are almost always more elegant than those that do.

Answer (score 3):

Actually `contextlib` provides a context manager that capture the `stdout` of your code called `redirect_stdout`.

Here is an example:

```
import io
from contextlib import redirect_stdout


func_str = 'print(3)'
stdout = io.StringIO()
with redirect_stdout(stdout):
    exec(func_str)

out = stdout.getvalue()
print(out, out.strip() == '3')
```

Output:

```
3
 True
```

**PS:** The code is inspired from [contextlib.redirect_stdout](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.redirect_stdout) documentation code example.

Comment: Nice find! I was thinking about writing my `swap_stdout` function in my answer as a context manager, but I see there is already one in the stdlib that does it.